# Show that the space of polynomials with real coefficients and $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ are isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

From the notes from my linear algebra course:

> Given a positive integer n, the vector spaces $\mathbb{P}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ are isomorphic.
>
> [To show this, define] $T: \mathbb{P}_n(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by
> $$
>      T \left( \sum_{j=0}^{n} p_j t^j \right) = \begin{pmatrix} p_0 \\ p_1 \\ \vdots \\ p_n \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}
>  $$
> and verify $T$ is linear and bijective.

I haven't had any good ideas on where to start by showing that $T$ is linear—the one thing that keeps coming to mind is for me to apply $T$ to each term in $\sum_{j=0}^{n} p_j t^j$, but that would obviously be circular since it assumes $T$ is linear. (*Edit*) Another thing I've tried is expressing the vector on the RHS, $(p_0, p_1, \ldots, p_n)^T$ as a linear combination $p_0 (1, 0, \ldots, 0)^T + p_1 (0, 1, \ldots, 0)^T + \ldots + p_n (0, 0, \ldots, 1)^T$, but I'm still not sure where I could even go using that approach; would I say that each basis vector could be expressed as a transformation, i.e. $(1, 0, \ldots, 0)^T = T\textbf{p}$, for some $\textbf{p} \in P_n(\mathbb{R})$? (*End edit*)

As for showing that $T$ is bijective, it seems clear that $T$ is injective since each $p \in \mathbb{P}_n(\mathbb{R})$ gets mapped to a unique $\textbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, and that $T$ is surjective since each polynomial has a representation as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$; however, I don't how to show that formally. What could I do here?

Comment: What's the problem with showing that $T$ is linear exactly? You can just take $p$ and $q$ two polynomials, and a scalar $\lambda$, and then it's fairly easy to show that $T(p + \lambda q) = T(p) + \lambda T(q)$ without much trouble.

Comment: @BrunoB Most approaches I try get me stuck. I'm going to edit in some attempts that I've done so future readers can see what I've tried (as I admittedly should have done to begin with when writing this question).

Answer (score 1):

Let $p,q$ be two polynomials, and $\lambda$ a real.
Then, we have:
$$\begin{split} T(p + \lambda q) &= T\left(\sum_{k = 0}^{n} p_k X^k + \lambda \sum_{k=0}^n q_k X^k\right)\\
&= T\left(\sum_{k = 0}^n (p_k + \lambda q_k) X^k\right)\\
&= \pmatrix{p_0 + \lambda q_0 \\ \vdots \\ p_n + \lambda q_n}\\
&= \pmatrix{p_0 \\ \vdots \\ p_n} + \lambda \pmatrix{q_0 \\ \vdots \\ q_n} = T(p) + \lambda T(q)\end{split}$$
Hence $T$ is linear.

Comment: Does $X^k$ represent the variable for the polynomial, i.e. $p(x)$?

Comment: @Mailbox Yes, it's just that I have been taught to use (and like using) $X$ for formal operations on polynomials. It doesn't matter as much for real and complex polynomials but see [this short Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_(variable)) for a context where a distinction between the polynomial $p = p(X)$ and the function $x \mapsto p(x)$ is needed. It's pretty much just a matter of personal preference in the current context though.